# Ubuntu 12.10 Unity not starting after 11/04 update

Tags: 12.10, unity, updates

After this Thursday updates when I login to my account Unity wont start anymore.
I have a pic of the how the system starts:
http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/2822/screenshotfrom201304131.png

And here the updates made:
http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/2822/screenshotfrom201304131.png

Answer (score 0):

You may have broken unity during upgrading some unity's dependency or due to upgrade of some package related to display driver, 
try running this in you terminal 
 *unity --reset*

Comment: Already tried, installing unity-reset and runing it. No success.

Comment: I also tried reseting compiz configs too. And my other users are facing the same problem.

Comment: you may also want to try **unity --replace** after reinstalling your graphics driver.

Comment: Solved the problem by reinstalling AMD drivers. One more question now. Is it possible to restore my compiz configuration after I reseted compiz config?

Comment: Glad, that worked for you..
Sorry, don't have much Idea on compiz. It doesnt work fine with my system so have disabled it. :(